# Angular: How to access JSON object in a recursive function

Tags: angular

I want to show the hierarchy where Groups have value. In my [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akgenv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) I tried

```
item.Groups.length > 0
```

but it not working.

For specification: Level 3 will not be shown cause its Groups value is zero and the result I want:

```
Level 1 > Level 1-1 > Level 1-1-1
Level 1 > Level 1-1
Level 2 > Level 2-1
```

Output html will be like this: [image: Output Image]

Comment: Hi, if you dont want to show level 3 because its group is empty, then why did you show the level 1 even if its group is empty

Comment: Is your condition on `groups` being empty or the `sublevels` being impty

Comment: In your example none of the `groups` at the top level have the value. Can you be more clear on it?

Comment: Level 1-1-1 parent is Level 1-1 and Level 1 is parent of Level 1-1. For this level 1 is shown. Actually I want to show parent to child hierarchy which have Groups value.

Comment: Do you want both `Level 1 > Level 1-1` and `Level 1 > Level 1-1 > Level 1-1-1`

Comment: My menu array is not fixed. Here values will be changed. I need to show breadcrumbs or a hierarchy of a Groups which have value. For example in my array:
Level 1 > Level 1-1 > Level 1-1-1
Level 1 > Level 1-1
Level 2 > Level 2-1 only have groups value

Comment: **Recursive function... Or just dealing with hierarchical data**? Only if you mean data. and it's coming from a database backend there are ways to do things with CTE's and SQL to produce a dataset with levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check this solution : [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ixcfwq) ?

Comment: Suppose now I add new groups in level-. For example: ' "ID": "03",
      "Name": "Level 3",
      "parentId": null,
      "sublevel": [],
      "Groups": [{
            "GroupID": "4",
            "GroupName": "group 4",
            "assigned": true
          }]' The out put not update.

Comment: What is the purpose of "Groups" property ? can you explain more ?

Comment: I add a image for better understand.Hope it will help you. I can say Groups is a common property of every parent/child. But its not fixed that every Groups has value. It maybe has value, or may not. I need the parent to child hierarchy breadcrumbs of Groups which have value. One important things, The json array will be updated dynamically.